# Function returns Array but output is not as expected

Tags: c++, xcode

The issue I'm having is I'm trying to return an array from the function `EnterNumber()` and display it in the main, but its coming out fairly crazy.  I went through with the debugger and the numbers are correct in the debugger, just not correct in once it prints to the screen.

[image: Here's a shot of the debugger after returning from the function]

[image: Here's a shot of what it prints]

I realize there's a global const int in my program, but it was sanctioned by my professor who wanted us to do it just this time for this program.

Just looking for a nudge on why its printing incorrectly.  Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void EnterNumber(int Number[]);

const int SIZE=20;

int main()
{
    int LargeNumber1[SIZE];
    int LargeNumber2[SIZE];

    for (int Counter1=0; Counter1<=19; ++Counter1)//zeros arrays out
    {
        LargeNumber1[Counter1]=0;
        LargeNumber2[Counter1]=0;
    }

    EnterNumber(LargeNumber1);

    for (int Counter2=0; Counter2<=19; ++Counter2)//display array 1 contents
    {
        cout << LargeNumber1[SIZE];
    }

    cout << "\n\n";

    EnterNumber(LargeNumber2);

    for (int Counter2=0; Counter2<=19; ++Counter2)//display array 2 contents
    {
        cout << LargeNumber2[SIZE];
    }

}

void EnterNumber(int Number[])
{
    int TemporaryArray[SIZE];
    int PlaceCounter;

    char Storage;

    PlaceCounter=0;

    for (int Counter1=0; Counter1<=19; ++Counter1)//zeros arrays out
    {
        TemporaryArray[Counter1]=0;
        Number[Counter1]=0;
    }

    cout << "Please enter a large number --> ";

    cin.get(Storage);

    while (Storage!='\n' && PlaceCounter<SIZE)//puts number in temp array - left aligned
    {
        TemporaryArray[PlaceCounter]=(Storage-'0');
        ++PlaceCounter;
        cin.get(Storage);
    }

    --PlaceCounter;//decrement one to get it to work properly with element style counting, else, extra zero at end

    for (int A=SIZE-1; PlaceCounter>=0; A--, PlaceCounter--)//transfers old array into new array, right aligned
    {
        Number[A]=TemporaryArray[PlaceCounter];
    }

    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I clicked the wrong tag, my apologies.  Fixed now.

Comment: `cout << LargeNumber1[SIZE];` --> `cout << LargeNumber1[Counter2];`

Comment: WOW!  That was all?  My mind is toasted today.  I had a really poor experience for the first time in my C++ lab portion today in class and it frustrated me to no end, probably what caused this simple oversight.  That was all that was causing the issue.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
for (int Counter2=0; Counter2<=19; ++Counter2)
{
    cout << LargeNumber1[SIZE];
}
```

should be this:

```
for (int Counter2=0; Counter2<SIZE; ++Counter2)
{
    cout << LargeNumber1[Counter2];
}
```

You were repeatedly printing a number that was just beyond the end of the array.

Comment: I can't believe how simple of an issue that was.  As I said in another comment, I had a rough day in my C++ lab, had all sorts of issues in class today and actually had to quit doing my lab.. I think my brain is still fried from that and it is showing up in this ridiculously silly screw up.  Thanks a ton

Comment: Happens to all of us. Sometimes all you need to do is take a break from staring at that screen. Best of luck!

Comment: What an amazing community this is.  I do my best to refrain from posting all of my frustrations and learn my mistakes on my own.. so that I do not annoy the members, but you guys are always super helpful.  Can't thank you guys enough.